# Expanding Accordion with new Titled Pane

Tags: java, accordion, javafx-2

I want to refill an  Accordion with a new collection of TitledPane, but I've found a problem expanding nodes in the accordion.

I guess that it's an issue of the JavaFX library. Because it also happen with the [sample provided in the manual for Accordion and TitledPane from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/accordion-titledpane.htm#). I take the original Example 22-5, and change it like this:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("TitledPane");
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 800, 250);
    scene.setFill(Color.GHOSTWHITE);

    final Label label = new Label("Initial");

    // --- Accordion
    final Accordion accordion = new Accordion ();                
    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new 
            Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageNames[i] + ".jpg"));
        pics[i] = new ImageView(images[i]);
        tps[i] = new TitledPane(imageNames[i],pics[i]); 
    }   
    accordion.getPanes().addAll(tps);        
    accordion.expandedPaneProperty().addListener(new 
        ChangeListener<TitledPane>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TitledPane> ov,
                TitledPane old_val, TitledPane new_val) {
                    if (new_val != null) {
                        label.setText("expanded: " +accordion.getExpandedPane().getText());
                    }
          }
    });

    HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
    Button buttonClear = new Button("Clear and refill");
    buttonClear.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {            
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.length; i++) {                    
                tps[i] = new TitledPane(imageNames[i]+" refill",pics[i]); 
            }
            accordion.getPanes().clear();
            accordion.getPanes().addAll(tps);
            accordion.getPanes().get(0).setExpanded(true);
        }
    });
    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 20));
    hbox.getChildren().setAll(label, accordion, buttonClear);

    Group root = (Group)scene.getRoot();
    root.getChildren().add(hbox);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

When I change the expanded TitledPane, the label takes its value. And I also added a button, that clear all the TitledPane in the Accordion, create a new ones and set the first TitledPane as Expanded.

So when I press the button, the accordion it's refilled, the label says that the First TitledPane it's expanded but the last one it's the one who seems selected, but without the image. This occurs the second time we press this button, or if we previously select one of the TitledPane.

And this thing it's precisely what I want to do. Clear all the TitledPane and refill it with new TitledPane, and it's giving the same weird result.

How can I clean all the TitledPane, create a new ones and set as expanded the first TitledPane without this side effects that I explain before?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I cannot fathom the meaning of your question, please put an exclamation mark after the appropriate sentence.

Comment: I think now the question it's clarified. If you don't understand anything, please tell me. Thank you.